# Using a combination of layouts in a single UICollectionView and UIViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a simple application that I'm working on where the user is presented with a `UITableViewController` of languages. When they click on any language, they're taken to a UIViewController with an embedded `UICollectionView`. This component is designed in the `Interface Builder`, where I have a custom reusable `UICollectionViewCell`. The reason I've done this is because on the fly, I can determine how many `UICollectionViewCells` to display.

It looks like this:

[image]

The grey box is the `UICollectionViewCell`. So this works as I expect because if I click on Language English for example, it displays three `UICollectionViewCells` and if I click on French, it displays one.

Right now, the `UICollectionViewCells` are all the same size which makes sense because they're displaying different images.

What I would like to achieve is essentially two sections. The first section is the `UICollectionViewCells` of the size in the image above and the second section to be be smaller `UICollectionViewCells`.

How can I achieve this in the interface builder? I cannot see options for Sections, like you can see in the `UITableViewController` settings.

Because I am using a `UICollectionViewCell` that spans across the width of the image, perhaps I could just use a `UITableViewController` with a custom height for each cell and then have sections?

I'm not sure on the correct approach to take here and any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be really easy to implement with the delegate inside the your viewcontroller code.
You can still create the cell in interface builder but connect the UITableview delegate to your viewcontroller class and use these methods accordingly

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In case you have a dynamic content your view controller might know the data you would want to present in those cells. In this case I would create a method that determine the size of the cell upon it's content.

Should look close to that

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                      layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   NSString *myContent = [self contentWithIndex:indexPath];
   CGSize size = [self sizeForContent:myContent];
   return size;


}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Or.Ron - I appreciate your thoughts on this. So with that method, I could use the indexPath to determine the size, but would I have to calculate each selection indexPath, because some may have 2 cells at the top and some may have 4. In my case, I'm not too sure how to achieve this properly. Please could I ask if you could provide a bit of an example of how this could be done in my case? Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks very much for that. Your answer now makes full sense and I appreciate your guidance on this.